# Date is in numeric data type field, would like to group by month using SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, date, numeric

I've been tasked to query a database using SQL Developer where the date is in a field type "numeric" (e.g. '20190101'). The ask is to provide an output by month and year, so DATEID between 20190101 and 20190131 would be January 2019. After searching online, I'm really at a loss on how to simplify this so I don't have to run a separate query for each month. Could someone provide some guidance?

Answer (score 0):

I would just divide the numeric value by 100 and retain the integer part. This is a simple way to extract the year and month part: for example, for any number between `20190101` and `20190131`, this would produce `201901`.

In most databases, you could express this with `floor()`:

```
select floor(mycol / 100), <some aggregate expressions>
from mytable
group by ceil(mycol / 100)
```

Comment: `SELECT CEIL(20200102/100) FROM dual;` would return 202002, not the expected 202001. However this is, IMO, not a good way of handling the OP's requirements. Why work with numbers when the OP is clearly after dates? (Poor db design notwithstanding!) Converting the number to a date is better, because it gives Oracle more information about the data and you get all the date handling thrown in.

Comment: @Boneist: my bad, I meant `floor()` of course, not `ceil()`. That being fixed, I understand your point on using dates rather than numbers. But since they are using numbers already, the division technique is a simple, efficient and straight-forward way to answer their request. If more date manipulation is needed (validation, formatting, and so on), then it is sure better to convert to date.

Comment: @VSM . . . For  what it is worth, I think this is the best answer to the question you asked.  I also think that you should fix your data model so dates are stored as dates.

Comment: Even though this might not be the "right" way, this answer worked perfectly for my needs because it was well explained and easy to understand -- and thank you for adding in the floor() correction. @GordonLinoff, I would love to fix the data model, but I'm a contractor that has been tasked to QC an already existing DB. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `to_date` to convert the number into DATE datatype and then `trunc` to truncate it to the first of the month, or `to_char` to turn it into month+year, e.g.:

```
SELECT SYSDATE,
       TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'mm') mnth_yr1,
       to_char(SYSDATE, 'fmMonth yyyy') mnth_yr2
FROM   dual;

SYSDATE             MNTH_YR1    MNTH_YR2
------------------- ----------- --------------
03/02/2020 15:56:02 01/02/2020  February 2020
```

Note the use of `fm` in the `to_char`'s format mask - this makes the Month output just the characters in the month, rather than adding extra spaces to make it the same length as the longest month.

Once you have your month/year, you can then use that to group by in an aggregate query, e.g.:

```
SELECT TRUNC(your_num_col, 'mm') mnth_yr,
       SUM(your_value_col)
FROM   your_table
GROUP BY TRUNC(your_num_col, 'mm');
```

Answer (score 0):

Another answer

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_date(20190101, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'MONTH YYYY') AS SOME_DATE FROM dual;

#result
SOME_DATE     |
--------------|
JANUARY   2019|
```